# In a neural network, how are weights adjusted between the third to last and second to last layer of neurons?

Tags: neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, algorithms, computational-statistics

I haven't been able to find much information that explains back propagation in simple terms. I would like to know what is happening (what is the algorithm) to be able to code one in java. I know that java is probably not the best language to use, but that's besides the point. I know how weights are adjusted between the last two layers, but how are the weights adjusted between the previous layers?

[image: A miscellaneous neural network]

Comment: The cool thing about backpropagation is that weights between the first and second layer are adjusted in just the same way as the ones between the second and final layers.